# Problema con SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined - Número de parámetro no válido: el parámetro no se definió

Tags: php, pdo

Buenas tengo una pregunta, le paso $table que es un nombre de una tabla y le paso $id que es un entero a esta funcion para hacer un select. Selecciono los campos de la tabla donde idusuario es igual al id que lo e pasado como parametro. Pero al ejecutarlo me sale este error. Que estoy haciendo mal.

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

```
static public function mactualizar($table, $id){
    $stmt=Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * from $table where idusuario=:id");
    $stmt -> bindParam(":idusuario", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Esto esta mal: `idusuario=:$id");` la sintaxis debe ser: `idusuario=:id");`

Comment: Lo cambie como me dijiste y sigue igual. Con el mismo error. Como el parametro $tabla lo paso en la consulta como $tabla, pense que el otro parametro tambien debia pasarlo asi. @BetaM

Answer (score 2):

En la consulta preparada el parámetro se llama `:id`:

```
SELECT * from $table where idusuario=:id
```

Por tanto, en el `bindParam` **debes usar el mismo nombre que usaste en la consulta preparada**.

Actualmente estás usando `:idusuario`, pero ese parámetro no existe, por eso el error: `parameters was not defined`.

Si lo pones así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores:

```
static public function mactualizar($table, $id){
    $stmt=Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * from $table where idusuario=:id");
    $stmt -> bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Ten en cuenta que los parámetros que se ponen con los dos puntos en las consultas preparadas son simplemente marcadores, y deben ser iguales en ambas partes. Claro está, por comprensión de código se suele poner igual que el nombre de la columna, pero eso no es obligatorio.

Dicho eso, este código también debería funcionar:

```
static public function mactualizar($table, $id){
    $stmt=Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * from $table where idusuario=:idusuario");
    $stmt -> bindParam(":idusuario", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
```